# Hello, how do i solve this driver python error?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, sms

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import random
numara = input("numarayi yaz ")
mesajSayisi = int(input("kac mesaj "))
sayi = random.randint(10000, 1000000)
sayi = str(sayi)
id = 'asdasd' + sayi
driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:\\Users\mutam\Desktop\sms_metin2\chromedriver.exe")
url = "https://www.hisarmt2.com/kayit-ol"
driver.Chrome.get(url)
```

when i run this code i get this error, anyone can help please?

```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:\\Users\mutam\Desktop\sms_metin2\chromedriver.exe")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\mutam\Desktop\sms_metin2\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:\\Users\mutam\Desktop\sms_metin2\chromedriver.exe")
```

Comment: That is not the whole error message. Please [edit] your question to show it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your exact issue is... In the newer versions of Selenium the driver path is depreciated. Try installing webdriver_manager and using this below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager #install webdriver_manager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('website')
```

Comment: driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())) Should be like so but close!